# Workflow failed. Causes: There was a problem refreshing your credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, service-accounts, dataflow, google-iam

I have a problem with dataflow, I need to execute a job and I get the following error:

```
Workflow failed. Causes: There was a problem refreshing your credentials. Please check:
1. Dataflow API is enabled for your project.
2. There is a robot service account for your project:
service-[project number]@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com should have access to your project. If this account does not appear in the permissions tab for your project, contact Dataflow support.
```

And I have created the service account and with permits within the project.

[Service account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JUaS.png)

so I still can not identify this error.
I have disabled the Dataflow API and reactivated and still nothing. Or if it is possible to regenerate this service account in order to execute a job?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Add the service account email into ***service_account_email*** option of your PipelineOptions.

```
 def get_pipeline_options(self):
      options = PipelineOptions( )

      gcp_options                                   = options.view_as( GoogleCloudOptions )
      gcp_options.job_name                          = "sampleflow"
      gcp_options.project                           = "etldemo-000000"
      gcp_options.staging_location                  = "gs://<bucket name>/stage"
      gcp_options.temp_location                     = "gs://<bucket name>/tmp"
      gcp_options.service_account_email             = "etldemo@etldemo-000000.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      options.view_as( StandardOptions ).runner     = 'DataflowRunner'

      return options
```